# Would a Periapt of Wound Closure protect a creature that does not get death saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, saving-throw

Death saving throws are usually reserved for PCs and very important NPCs.  In contrast, most creatures simply die when reduced to 0 HP.

If a creature is attuned to a *periapt of wound closure*, but does not get death saving throws, will this stop them from dying if they aren't instantly killed by massive damage?

Answer (score 28):

The relevant rule on [monsters and death saving throws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MonstersandDeath) says:

> Most DMs have a monster die the instant it drops to 0 hit points, rather than having it fall unconscious and make death saving throws.
>
> Mighty villains and special nonplayer characters are common exceptions; the DM might have them fall unconscious and follow the same rules as player characters.

So I suppose we would expect that, if an NPC were special enough to have a magic item, the DM would probably consider that NPC to be special enough to get death saves.

A different way to think of this: it's not that random monsters *shouldn't* get death saves, it's just that it's too much work for the DM to roll them, so most DMs will just call them dead to avoid bookkeeping. If a monster is wearing a periapt of wound closure, the DM would likely  call them unconscious-but-stable to avoid bookkeeping.

In my own games, I assume defeated opponents are dead, unless one of the PCs expresses an interest in keeping them alive for interrogation, in which case I go back and roll the death saves to see if they're alive. That seems to work fine.

Ultimately it's up to the DM, though.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  The Periapt should work to stabilize any creature that isn't killed outright by massive damage, just simply RAW.

I see the statement "Most DMs have a monster die the instant it drops to 0 hit points, rather than having it fall unconscious and make death saving throws." as being a convenience, or a suggestion, rather than a rule.

In my world, I consider all creatures to get the benefits of unconsciousness and death saves.  I only actually roll them at the time if it matters, but I count them.  If, in a fight, the party wins and just leaves the monsters for dead, I'll check afterward to see how many died, and how many wake up eventually and might hold a grudge in the future.

I would definitely count any of them that had a Periapt as surviving.

Answer (score -2):

## No

[Periapt of Wound Closure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/periapt-of-wound-closure) description states

> While you wear this pendant, you stabilize whenever you are dying at the start of your turn.

Providing a creature is killed on someone else's turn, at the start of its own turn it would be already dead, not dying. Even if a creature got its death saving throws, it still can be killed before its turn starts.